# How to create a videoplayer for website that can play m3u playlist?

Tags: jquery, jwplayer, video-player

One question is bothering me for days, isn't there really no videoplayer out there that can play video streams from m3u file?

I have been searching several days from google but havent found any solution.

I have an M3U file formated like this:

> ```
> #EXTM3U
> #EXTINF:0 group-title="Channels",Channel 1
> http://host.com/channel1.ch
> #EXTINF:0 group-title="Channels",Channel 2
> http://host.com/channel2.ch
> ```

All i want to achive is to have embeded videoplayer on website, and playlist beside it where user can select stream to play on video player.

I found this project:
https://github.com/aitorciki/jquery-playlist

And tried it like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.playlist.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('video').playlistParser();
    });
</script>
<video id="video" src="http://example.com/playlist.m3u" width="768" height="432"></video>
```

But this doesnt work neighter...

Comment: I've researched this topic before and ultimately concluded that the only common players that can play m3u playlists in a plugin are Windows Media Player and Quicktime. VLC Media Player claims to be able to but when using VLC Media Player it just gives a black screen. This is problematic because when using the proper mimetype for m3u files VLC is the default, leaving the user with nothing but a black screen. A better option might be to use VirtualDub, Quicktime, or Freemake to merge your photos into one video.

Comment: JW Player supports only RSS.

Comment: Really strange that no modern videoplayer supports m3u playlists for live streaming...  so only way would be to write somekind of converter from M3U to RSS ? :/

Answer (score 0):

The JW Player support RSS, not M3U - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-support

Also, you can't embed the JW Player using a  tag, it is done using our embedder, called jwplayer.js - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference

We do support M3U8 though (HLS), but not M3U.

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406722-rss-playlist-embed - RSS